# Creating custom Quantiles within data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

If i have the following table:

```
tibble(year = c("2020", "2020", "2020","2021", "2021", "2021"),
       website  = c("facebook", "google", "youtube","facebook", "google", "youtube"), 
       method = c("laptop", "laptop", "laptop", "mobile", "mobile", "mobile"), 
       values = c(10,30,60, 90,25, 40))
```

How can i try to go about creating a column based on a custom q-tile of the numbers in the value column.

For example, if i have the following custom q-tile conditions:

Risky - > 50%
Neither - 25-50%
Safe - <25%

These are basically saying for the numbers in the values column, calculate what their ranking based on the q-tile conditions above and give them a rank value of 1,2,3 accordingly.

The final table should look like this:

```
tibble(year = c("2020", "2020", "2020","2021", "2021", "2021"),
       website  = c("facebook", "google", "youtube","facebook", "google", "youtube"), 
       method = c("laptop", "laptop", "laptop", "mobile", "mobile", "mobile"), 
       values = c(10,30,60, 90,25, 40), 
       rank = c(3,2,1,1,3,2))
```

I know that the table will have to be grouped by year and method along, so the code will look like this:

```
df %>% group_by(year, method) %>% mutate(rank = quantile(???))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5))` to get cutpoints and pass them into `findInterval()`. Note that `findInterval()` is similar to `cut(*, labels = FALSE)` but is more efficient.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year, method) %>%
  mutate(rank = findInterval(-values, quantile(-values, c(0.25, 0.5)), left.open = TRUE) + 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   year  website  method values  rank
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2020  facebook laptop     10     3
# 2 2020  google   laptop     30     2
# 3 2020  youtube  laptop     60     1
# 4 2021  facebook mobile     90     1
# 5 2021  google   mobile     25     3
# 6 2021  youtube  mobile     40     2
```

---

If you want labels rather than ranks, use `cut()`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(year, method) %>%
  mutate(rank = cut(values, quantile(values, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1)),
                    c("Safe", "Neither", "Risky"), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   year  website  method values rank   
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <fct>  
# 1 2020  facebook laptop     10 Safe   
# 2 2020  google   laptop     30 Neither
# 3 2020  youtube  laptop     60 Risky  
# 4 2021  facebook mobile     90 Risky  
# 5 2021  google   mobile     25 Safe   
# 6 2021  youtube  mobile     40 Neither
```

Comment: If i were to have NA values - how does this affect the code?

Comment: @BeansOnToast just add `na.rm = TRUE` into `quantile()`.

Comment: it seems to give this error `Caused by error in `findInterval()`:
! 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs` but i resolved it by doing a `mutate(ifelse(is.na(values), 0, values))` then it worked

Comment: @BeansOnToast In my view, `NA` should be excluded when calculating quantiles, i.e. set `na.rm = TRUE` into `quantile()`. If you replace `NA` with zeros, the quantiles will change.

Comment: For some reason it keeps causing the above error when entering na.rm=TRUE - but i would like to keep the na values so i'll find a work around

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ntile` function from `dplyr` to create quantiles:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(year, method) %>%
  mutate(rank = ntile(values, 4))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
# Groups:   year, method [2]
  year  website  method values  rank
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 2020  facebook laptop     10     1
2 2020  google   laptop     30     2
3 2020  youtube  laptop     60     3
4 2021  facebook mobile     90     3
5 2021  google   mobile     25     1
6 2021  youtube  mobile     40     2
```

Comment: But how does it know what the ntile ranks are? as 1/4 means 4 separate 25% tiles - in my example there are only 3

Comment: Or should i run this followed by a ifelse statement at the end to convert any value >3 into a 3?

Comment: You can change the function to `ntile(values, 3)`.

Comment: I've just checked the documentation and it states that this is creating 3 groups? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BurStMisc/versions/1.1/topics/ntile - but that would mean 1/3 - in my case there is those > 50, between 25-50 and less than 25 , this means 3 distinct groups not 1/3 evenly across

Comment: You can use this: `mutate(rank = cut(x = ntile(values, 100), 
                    breaks = c(25, 50, 100), 
                    include.lowest = TRUE, 
                    right = FALSE, labels = FALSE))` where `breaks` are the custom ranges you want right? If you share more data I can reproduce that for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(year, method) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(-cut(values, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(values, probs = c(0.25, 0.50), names = F), Inf), labels = F)))

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   year, method [2]
#   year  website  method values  rank
#   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2020  facebook laptop     10     3
# 2 2020  google   laptop     30     2
# 3 2020  youtube  laptop     60     1
# 4 2021  facebook mobile     90     1
# 5 2021  google   mobile     25     3
# 6 2021  youtube  mobile     40     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A `{santoku}` one-liner:

```r
mutate(df,
  rank = santoku::chop_quantiles(rank, c(0.25, 0.5), 
                                   labels = c("Safe", "Neither", "Risky"))
)
```